# Outlook displays "mshtml.HTMLTableRowClass" instead of Html Row

Tags: html, powershell, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to get a row of a table from a Webpage and fill the HTML Code into an HTML E-Mail. I'm using Powershell for this.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate(www.example.com) 

$htmlDetailedRow = $ie.document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("className")
```

Above you see how I get the element that I want to display in my E-Mail.

```
$body = @"
<html>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <table>
            $htmlDetailedRow
       </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
"@
```

Above you see my HTML for the Email.

```
 <tr class="className">
  <td colspan="5" style="border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; padding: 0">
    <table class="clean" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0; width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 25%"><i>Date</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 25%">22.03.2022</td>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 30%">Text</td>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 15%">1</td>
          <td style="text-align: left; width: 15%">5.136</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Above you can see the row I want to grab from the Webpage. My idea is to take the row and insert into a table in my Email HTML. The Webpage is behind a Login so unfortunately I can't link to the Page.

The HTML is working fine but the $htmlDetailedRow wont display right. Instead it displays "**mshtml.HTMLTableRowClass**". I know I have to convert $htmlDetailedRow somehow, but I have no idea how.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You do not include any sample data or even a specific website, therefore it is difficult to give you a specific answer back (see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). As a general solution, to read html tables you might want to try (or reverse engineer): [Read-HtmlTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Read-HtmlTable) (see also: [project site](https://github.com/iRon7/Read-HtmlTable)) which is able to read a lot of twisted html tables and convert them to PowerShell objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Because I was using getElementsByClassName("className"), it returned a array back. So to get to the innerHtml i had to acess like this.

```
$htmlDetailedRow = $ie.document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("className")
    
$htmlDetailedRow[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see what the object `$htmlDetailedRow` looks like.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate(www.example.com) 

$htmlDetailedRow = $ie.document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("className")

$htmlDetailedRow | get-member | clip
```

Then you can just paste into a new code block when editing your question.

---

It looks like you're trying to download the content of a webpage and parse it for a table. I created a function that does that, you can grab it from [here](https://github.com/tonypags/PsDevTools/blob/aadbc68525482edf1ab04e9e5d44be3627681632/ConvertFrom-Html.ps1). Check out the examples.

---

This is a bit off-topic, but it's best to stay away from internet explorer, or any app or tech that is end of life. No matter how benign your use case, it creates more work for you in the future and is less secure. In this case, like, REALLY less secure!

Invoke-WebRequest (Alias iwr) is the PowerShell way to get data from a web resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do "$htmlDetailedRow | get-member | clip" but it says I have to provide an Object for Get-Member.

Comment: That will happen if the variable value is null. The variable needs to be populated. Run your first 4 lines of code in your OP, then run that get-member command. (I edited my answer to that effect)